# Probable DNS issues on server 2008 domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Symptoms:
Workstations sporadically lose connection to certain websites (internal and external).  Example: A workstation will get a time-out error when attempting to navigate to google.com but will continue to listen to pandora uninterupted while also being able to visit other internal and external websites.  This issue exists in IE 10, FF, Chrome and Opera.

This network also uses VoIP phones, which have not lost connections during phone calls (internal or external) as well.

**Troubleshooting performed so far:**

- Checked servers DNS forwarders, they are 75.75.75.75, 75.75.76.76 and
  8.8.8.8...
- Checked servers event viewer for anything out of the ordinary.  Dcom
  errors aside, nothing stands out to me.
- Added secondary public DNS to a test group of workstations (8.8.8.8),
  issue persists.

The network is all in a single VLAN at the moment (we are waiting to resolve this issue before proceeding with segmentation).  We are almost maxing out our DHCP pool daily, usually servicing around 230 devices.

My gut feeling is we might be taxing the single internal DNS server with requests, causing the issue we are seeing but I am uncertain how to verify this guess.

I have done a few pcaps on the test workstation (primary DNS internal, secondary DNS 8.8.8.8) while browsing websites.  The workstation starts off using the internal DNS, then after 60 seconds or less it starts using both internal and external DNS then transitions to using just external DNS.  I feel this lends some weight to my guess above, but do not have the experience to know if this is normal DNS behavior or not.

**tl;dr
Does anyone have a good method for troubleshooting DNS issues on a windows domain in a typical small business?**

Comment: `Added secondary public DNS to a test group of workstations (8.8.8.8), issue persists.` - Stop doing that. `Does anyone have a good method for troubleshooting DNS issues on a windows domain in a typical small business?` - Yes. Use nslookup on the client and the DNS server when the issue occurs and check DNS resolution for the websites you're having problems with. Use Wireshark or some other network capture program to capture traffic on a client when the problem occurs.

Comment: If the problem occurs when navigating to internal websites then the problem isn't related to external DNS name resolution, unless these websites use an FQDN that your internal DNS server isn't authoritative for.

Comment: The problem exists for such a small amount of time and appears to occur at random that it's like trying to capture lightning in a bottle.  A user will call us to notify us of a perceived outage, then by the time we hang up the problem is gone.

Comment: @joeqwerty I can setup wireshark to save pcaps in 5 minute intervals and run it on several end points until a report rolls in.

Comment: For an additional troubleshooting step, go into the advanced properties of your network adapter, there should be a bunch of checkboxes that list the services bound to the interface. Uncheck the IPv6 service so it's no longer bound to the interface and try again. If this makes things work a lot better, then you (or your upstream) are not handling IPv6 traffic correctly. This is a common issue I've found on several folks networks.

Comment: @erik toft I was out of the country for two weeks so I was unable to troubleshoot this until now.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @joeqwerty I have two pcaps from a workstation that has been experiencing the issue. The first one is when DNS is working properly.  The second is when the user said they noticed the issue.  In the second pcap, what I see is 120 seconds (exactly 120) of no responses from the server.  Any idea what causes a DNS server to stop responding to queries?  Pcap #1 (normal DNS behavior..I think) http://i62.tinypic.com/24cedrk.jpg    Pcap #2 (abnormal DNS) http://i61.tinypic.com/slpd6r.jpg    The black bars are the internal DNS server FYI.